# How do I calculate this probability question?

Tags: probability

How do I answer the following question:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two events such that $P(B) = \frac 14$ and $P(A|B^c) =\frac 13$.
>
> Compute $P(A \cup B)$

The answer is $\frac 12$, but I don't understand why.

Comment: What do you know about probability? Adding some details about the techniques you have learnt about can help people write an answer at the right level of knowledge for you

Comment: Also, did you mean $P(A|B^c)$ or $P(A|B\wedge c)$?

Comment: @lioness99a `B^c` was clearly in reference to the complementary event of $B$... not some wedge or logical and between $B$ and  $c$.  It should be obvious since otherwise the question is ambiguous and would vary depending on what object $c$ is.

Comment: Fair enough, I've never seen `B^c` used for complement, only ever `B'`, and it's always worth checking when a user has used ambiguous, non-MathJax-ed notation

Comment: @lioness99a [Complementary events on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_event).  "The complement of an event A is usually denoted as $A′$, $A^c$, $\neg A$ or $\overline{A}$."  I suggest familiarizing yourself with multiple variants of all common operations in whatever problem types you participate with most.

Comment: I'm not doubting you, just saying I had never come across it before which is why I asked OP to clarify...

Comment: Have you made a *Venn diagram* ?

Comment: As a concrete instance of this, consider flipping a coin twice. Then the probabilities of interest can be produced by having $A$ be the event where the first coin comes up heads and $B$ be the event where both coins flip heads.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$P(A\cup B) = P(B)+P(A\setminus B)$$

and

$$P(A\setminus B) = P(A\cap B^c)$$

---

*Solution:*

> Continuing, $P(A\cap B^c) = P(B^c)P(A\mid B^c)$ as well as $P(B^c)=1-P(B)$

$~$

> And so we had $P(A\cup B) = P(B)+(1-P(B))P(A\mid B^c) = \dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{3}{4}\cdot\dfrac{1}{3} = \dfrac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

P(B)=1/4 ,P(A|BC)=1/3

P(BC)=1-P(B)

P(BC)=3/4

P(A|BC)=P(AnBC)/P(BC)

P(AnBC)= P(A|BC). P(BC)

P(AnBC)=1/4

P(AnBC)=P(A).P(BC)

P(A)= P(AnBC)/ P(BC)

P(A)=1/3

P(AnB)= P(A).P(B)

P(AnB)=1/12

P(AUB)= P(A)+P(B)-P(AnB)

P(AUB)=1/2